# CSS font declaration question

Tags: css, fonts

whats the difference between this:

```
font-family: Arial, helevetica;
```

and this:

```
font: arial/ helvetica;
```

I've seen both but not really sure of the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the slash (`/`) a typo? Because the only slash I can image in the `font:` property is the one denoting font-size and line-height (e.g. `16px/20px`)

Anyway, `font:` is the property that lets you set several font properties at once, whereas `font-family` obviously only lets you set the font face. With `font:` you can also set size, bold/italic, line-height and variant:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.5em;
font-family: verdana,sans-serif
```

Is the same as:

```
font: bold italic small-caps 1em/1.5em verdana,sans-serif;
```

You can omit properties that are already set, too. For just size, family and bold:

```
font: bold 1em arial,verdana;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this question.

As [@Stephan Muller said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4376433/552067) the slash could just be a typo trying to denote the font-size and line-height, however there can also be a slash in some fonts like these:

```
font-family: Copperplate / Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
font-family: Gill Sans / Gill Sans MT, sans-serif;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The slash is a shorthand used to set font size and line height at the same time. So, the syntax is of the shorthand you have is incorrect.

```
font: 12px/14px Arial, helvetica;
```

is the only correct usage of the slash. In this example it would set the font size to 12px, the line height to 14px and the font family to Arial, helvetica.